# Is it a good solution to use both Starling and pure AS3 in a mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, starling-framework

Ive searched the .net for this question, but from what I have red.... there isnt a concrete opinion on the subject, so i decided to ask here.
I would like to know, if it is a good idea to use plain AS3 for the navigation part of the game ( home/options/help/pickALevel/ screens) and the actual game/gameplay to be coded with Starling framework? What cons and pros does it have? Or it is a better idea to just code all your app in one framework. 
Cheers

Comment: This is a QA Site. if you're looking for opinions, you should go to forums, messageboards, imageboards and so on. I have no experience whatsoever with Starling, but yes, in my opinion it is better to segregate the game from the UI in most cases.

Comment: I dont quite get why dont you approve this question/down vete it .... when Im asking for something that I think stackoverflow is ment for - i.e. people with practice in this area (that have met this problem) to share their knowledge. Also, if you actually red the question, you would have noticed that I did search for this (i.e. in forums/ sites ). But I guess its easier to read between the lines and down vote a legit and meaningful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both is fine and has no cons.

Using any Stage3D features requires loading times (Texture upload) which are slow on mobile and cause crashes when GPU allocated memory runs out.

Using classic display list helps reducing Texture upload and crashes due to GPU memory saturation.

I don't recommend using Starling though but it's true that many coders don't have any other choices. It's a slow framework (compared to what Stage3D truly offers), its author tried to enforce the unique use of Starling by mirroring all Flash classes (Sprite, DisplayObject, etc ...) making the use of both classic and Starling objects difficult in one given project, its author instead of using the Flash event system created a custom one with no inheritance relation to the Flash event system making Starling events incompatible with Flash events. Starling is just not a good framework.

Comment: Personally, this is the first time I've heard Starling described as "not a good framework." Do you have any links that explain why? Do you have any comparable examples of good GPU frameworks to contrast it with?

Comment: I've given a couple example as to why I have that opinion. Personally I've made my own and got a big speed boost in comparison. It's too technical and would take too long to explain why here but I believe the problem of Starling is that it was designed to be beginner friendly and that explains the design choices of the author. I recommend Starling for beginners and any coder without the knowledge to create their own engine. In any other cases create your own engine or use a more experienced coder oriented one.

Comment: Well, if it's slower than using Stage3D directly that certainly doesn't make it a bad framework. All frameworks introduce inefficiency (usually with performance costs) due to the code abstractions that make them easier to use. Any other reasons? If so, I understand it could be too much to explain here, hence any links? I am also curious what other "more experienced coder oriented" frameworks there are out there. I'm not dismissing your opinion, just looking for some concrete evidence because it's of interest to me.

Comment: I don't know if it's still supported but genome2d was performing much better than Starling but like I said it was certainly not for beginners. The author had sporadic support and made the core engine unavailable for edit so I decided to create my own for my own needs. My work is not public. The speed of that type of engine is not just about rendering (which Starling is the slowest at) but also uploading (which can be done in a few different ways) overall you got a uploading and rendering speed and Starling is the worst at it by design.

Comment: The guilty design of Starling (aimed at beginners) is to simulate the classic Flash Display List with Sprite, DisplayObject, addChild, etc ... which is a dream for beginners but the GPU doesn't render that way (painting algorithm) and so Starling must take extra steps to render everything. To get best performance from Stage3D the classic display list idea must be dropped altogether so collecting all data for drawing is faster. Different systems can be implemented but obviously beginners would have hard time with it.

Comment: It wasn't made "for beginnings", it was made with the idea of making the transition easier for users experienced with the vanilla display list. It's specifically designed to be a Stage3D equivalent replacement, which also makes it relatively easy to port native AS3 code into Starling. You speak as if every project has the time and budget for the luxury of coding its own engine, or porting an existing project to a radically new API, but in the real world budgets are often limited and release dates are often looming.

Comment: At the point you're coding your own Stage3D engine, you might as well be going with a more modern platform like Unity.

Comment: Unity has its shortcomings too, reusability is far easier and superior with AS3 dev. It is difficult (not impossible but difficult) to share efficiently code and assets between projects in Unity, doing so with AS3 projects of any kind is easy since it was designed that way.

Comment: Starling cannot be a Stage3D equivalent or replacement of any kind since it is build on top of Stage3D, no Stage3D no Starling. As of "porting native AS3 code into Starling" doesn't make much sense either since Starling is made and work only in AS3. I had a few vibrant debates with Starling author and openly criticized its framework design decisions to which he unfortunately had no answers. That framework was made for beginners in the hope to attract heavy traffic, it should have been made for professionals to attract quality.